# How do I stop scrolling of page when overlay div is visible?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events

The page I'm working with sometimes displays a modal layover with a div (position: fixed) > div (position: relative; width/height: 100%) > div (position: absolute; left/right: 50%).

Both on mobile devices and on Chrome/Safari on the desktop, swiping still scrolls the page behind the layover. Can I prevent this with JavaScript or CSS, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on desktop browsers, there are two events related to scrolling: `scroll` and `mousewheel`. The former occurs when an element is scrolled, which cannot be prevented.

What you're looking to do is catch the `mousewheel` event on the overlay and prevent its default action. You can do that with JavaScript and jQuery like so:

```
$('#overlay').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This won't work in IE and Firefox, however. For browser compatibility details, see [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html).

There appears to be no consistent way of doing this on mobile browsers, nor with scrolling via the touchpad on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

this is true, but to also support mobile devices for web applications, use this:

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
```

}